# Securing GWT servlets with Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, gwt, spring-security, web.xml

I'm writing a GWT application secured with Spring security. Logging in works fine, but authorization doesn't.

I've tried using @Secured and @PreAuthorize annotations on my methods and that didn't work either.

For instance, this is a code snippet from AppUserServiceImpl

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR")
    @Override
    public List<AppUser> fetch(Integer startRow, Integer endRow, Map criteria) {
        return appUserManagerBean.getUsers(criteria);
    }
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">


<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/testapplication/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/gwt/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/security/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/testapplication/appUserService*" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>

    <form-login
            login-page="/login.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/security/error.html"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            />
</http>
<beans:bean id="appUserService" class="com.test.testapplication.server.admin.appuser.AppUserServiceImpl"/>


<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
[DATASOURCE CONFIGURATION]
</beans:bean>
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" />
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="sha" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                           users-by-username-query="select username,password,DECODE(enabled,'Y',1,'N',0) as enabled from APP_USER where username=?"

                           authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.role from APP_USER u, APP_USER_ROLE ur
                                                          where u.id = ur.APP_USER_ID and u.username =?  "

                />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

To test, I'm trying to secure 'appUserService'.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appUserService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.testapplication.server.admin.appuser.AppUserServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<!-- Spring security filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- Spring listener -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>testapplication.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I'm looking for the simplest solution and I would prefer not to use AspectJ, help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate on your usage of @Secured and @PreAuthorize?
Are you using them at the web layer or at the service layer?
Can you add some snippets of the above?

Comment: Sure thing. It doesn't matter to me whether I'll be able to use them at the client or server layer though.

Comment: I have written a simple test and tried this with spring 3.1.0 and 3.1.3 and it worked fine. Can you specify spring and spring-security versions (your pom?)

Comment: I'm using 3.0.7 and I don't use Maven, so no pom

Answer (score 1):

Where are you mapping your servlet to particular path?

I'm using [gwt-sl](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-sl/) for integration of RemoteServiceServlets and Spring.
Define Dispatcher servlet in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gwtservice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And declaration and mapping for your gwt-servlet:

```
<bean name="DeviceListenerServlet" class="your.package.your.SomeService"/>
<bean id="urlMappingGWT" class="org.gwtwidgets.server.spring.GWTHandler">
    <property name="mappings">
        <map>
            <entry key="/service" value-ref="DriverServiceImpl"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And change Annotation in your RemoteService class (in my example it will be @RemoteServiceRelativePath("gwtservice/service")).

Now you can use you @Secured annotation (if you added )

Hope this help.

Comment: How would I go about installing gwt-sl? The site doesn't specify how to do it. Should I just import the jar into my lib folder?